# Jquery: How is the simple way to click don't work in child elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Click on "child" also make the alert work.
But what's the simple way to make click don't work on child elements?

Here is an example: https://fiddle.jshell.net/k8t5dpg2/

Html

```
<div id="secondary"> 1
<a>child</a>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$('#secondary').click(function () {       
    alert('something')
                        });
```

Comment: any child? do not add the `click` binding to.. (I guess I do not understand the question, can you elaborate?)

Comment: pass the event object to your function and test its `target` - https://fiddle.jshell.net/k8t5dpg2/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `event.target` to determine what is being clicked.

Example:

```
$('#secondary').click(function (event) {
    var target = $(event.target);
    if (target.is(this)) {
       alert('something');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an id to the child and :

```
$("#child").click(function () {       
    return false;
});
```

Comment: this is a bad approach for a number of reasons. you're adding additional event handlers which you don't need, you're returning false which is preventing default and stopping the event from propagating

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
$('#secondary').click(function (event) {
      if(event.target.nodeName ==='A') {
            return false;
      }else{
        alert('something');

       }
 });
```